# Python - create an ascending integer number

Tags: python

Can anyone please remind me how can i create an ascending **integer** number by given the numbers of the digits?

example:

```
y(3) -> 123
y(5) -> 12345
y(8) -> 12345678
```

Thank you

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: @RobertH i suppose he tried to ask stackoverflow :^)

Answer (score 12):

For values in the range 1 to 10, how about:

```
def y(size):
    return 1234567890 / (10**(10-size))

for size in range(1,11):
    print y(size)
```

Gives:

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
123456
1234567
12345678
123456789
1234567890
```

As an alternative way of thinking about it, try:

```
def y(size):
    return int("1234567890"[:size])
```

Comment: Elegant, and it is the fastest; i didn't though so much operations would be faster than a slice, bravo.

Comment: Indeed... have updated.

Comment: I think this function has no plausible definition for `size=10` since `...890` is not ascending anymore. There's nothing after 9 in base 10.

Answer (score 4):

```
def y(n):
    if n<=0:
        return n
    return int("".join(str(a) for a in range(1,n+1)))
```

As stated by @bufh:

```
def y(n):
    if n<=0:
        return n
    return int("".join(map(str,range(1,n+1))))
```

Comment: Shorter: `int(''.join(map(str, range(n+1))[1:]) or n)`

Comment: @bufh awesome yeah will try and tell

Comment: @bufh Why not `int(''.join(map(str, range(1, n + 1))))`?

Comment: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found

Comment: Could you provide the input where the error occurred @Assafbaruch

Comment: @PeterWood speaking about the slice: oh, no reason really, just for fun (^_^) otherwise the `or n` support values under one

Comment: @bufh you didn't have the `or n` when I commented.

Comment: The brackets aren't necessary, i.e. `join(str(a) for a in range(1,n+1))` should work. It's a generator comprehension instead of a list one.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu yes indeed edited

Answer (score 3):

You can create a range and then append the numbers to a string before moving back to an integer:

```
def y(size):
    mynum = ""
    for num in range(1, size+1):
        mynum += str(num)
    return int(mynum)

print("Number is %d" % y(8))
```

This is for Python 3. Python 2 doesn't require parentheses for the `print` function.

Comment: if i remember right should be an built in function which return a numbers for x to y. something like {print [x:y:1]}

Comment: @Assafbaruch that's what `range` does. Why would you expect `[x:y:1]` to do *anything* besides a `SyntaxError`?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to perform any string operations as proposed by the other answers; you could count from 1 to `x`, repeatedly multiplying the result by 10 and adding the current value:

```
def y(x):
    result = 0
    for i in range(1, x + 1):
        result = result * 10 + i
    return result
```

A recursive definition makes this algorithm fairly concise:

```
def y(x):
    return 0 if x <= 0 else y(x - 1) * 10 + x
```

Comment: You save a little bit of heap memory in exchange for increased stack memory by making it recursive. Still, if you want to avoid creating string objects, this works well.

Comment: does not work well with `0` or values overs `9`

Comment: @bufh: Well how is `y` defined for 0 (i.e. no digits) and values > 9 if it's supposed to return an integer? You cannot have integers with zero digits.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe you can have a null string, like the other answer proposing string operations [*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31430044/248390) ;^)

Comment: @bufh Right, except that the task is to yield an 'ascending integer number' (the 'integer' is even bold). Furthermore, even a string won't help with argument values > 9. The function `y` is plain undefined for values lower than 1 or greater than 9 (in base 10, at least).

Comment: oook, so i suggest `int('123456789'[:x])`, it save stack, recursion and is the shortest (and also [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit) rate it twice faster which is irrelevant ;^)

Comment: @bufh Yeah I think that would work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can join an empty string with each number in the range, then convert to an integer:

```
def y(size):
    return int(''.join(str(value)
                       for value in range(1, size + 1)))
```

You can repeatedly multiply by 10 adding each number in the range:

```
def y(size):
    return reduce((lambda total, digit: (total * 10) + digit),
                  range(1, size + 1))
```

You can map the string constructor to each number in the range, and join them together, then convert to an integer:

```
def y(size):
    return int(''.join(map(str, range(1, size + 1))))
```

Obviously, there are many other ways, but these are quite succinct.